# Specific application development

Tags: facebook

I want to build specific applications for Facebook, and construction of the application shows a lot of money.
Therefore, I would like to contact Facebook before I start to develop it.
How do I do this?
Another question,
Is there a problem selling items on Facebook? (By credit card). For example, there is a shoe company and I want to sell her items on Facebook? Or I could just turn from application to another page where he will continue to carry out the buying?

I can not find the help that Facebook's policies.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to contact Facebook before I start to develop it.

The best way would be to talk to people you know who might know Mark Zuckerberg & co. But that is out of reach of most people. If you have a great idea and you do well, they will come to you.

> Is there a problem selling items on Facebook? (By credit card)

As you probably know, [Facebook Credits](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CD4QFjAB&url=http://www.facebook.com/help/credits&ei=q1ooT7n7CYLcggeSxbD0BA&usg=AFQjCNFGzKNQMstTaxJ5sObVe2UiUDNJHg&sig2=67YOs9nwM0k3UeamAq0Csw) has not caught up as much as facebook would like. Facebook wants a piece of the action on the e-commerce happening on facebook apps so they might (just speculation here) try to force you to conduct in-app purchases through them.

> I could just turn from application to another page where he will continue to carry out the buying?

I would just say yes. If you are big enough for facebook to bother harassing you, then congratulations on your growth. This only applies to apps. If you want to make a facebook [page](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CE0QFjAB&url=http://www.facebook.com/pages/&ei=LlwoT5aiHoiZgwf5tcSSBQ&usg=AFQjCNEujbhgT5EnyzfGFm-cUyK1ftjfgA&sig2=DH35zCGxenyx4WY0hCHbXw), you can pretty much do anything you like because you are just redirecting people to your external e-commerce site.

Comment: fantastic answer... hope it gets accepted!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply,
But I do not want that Facebook will come to me, I just do not want that after investing the money in the project, Facebook decided it stops my application.
And from what you're saying I take a big risk that the representative that I could not contact him?

Only to understand the situation, the project is the size of several million dollars, and if Facebook decided to stop me I'm in big trouble.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Probably it would be quickest to try making some friends in the valley. If I were you, I'd take a long and hard look (and then some) at the problem before investing that much money into someone else's platform, regardless of any assurances that Mark and co. can give me. I am not trying to berate you but not all of us can be as clever as Pincus. Just ask @loic about his experience with Seesmic. (and twitter is arguably much less "evil" than facebook.)